# MySQL if where not found then insert

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

As this could appear as a classic "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" question - it is not.

I have a table with some meta values it goes like:

```
meta_id   |   user_id   |   meta_type   |   meta_value
```

Thing is there actually can be more entries with the same `user_id`&&`meta_type` what must not repeat is the entries with the same `user_id`&&`meta_type`&&`meta_value`. Well I could add an unique index for these, but I am afraid of one thing - the `meta_value` is a *longtext* so it could contain larger data.

So when I want to create the unique key (so then I could use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE), I get an error:

`#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'meta_hodnota' used in key specification without a key length`

And when I tried to add some limit this popped out:

```
#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

That is just too low for possible entry. So the question is how this key actually work:

1. It is just saying **how long part of the column will the MySQL check for duplicity** and does not modify the posibility of having the max. column value size (max(longtext)) 
    **Note:** I care for this tripple duplicity only for smaller entries, I dont care for duplicity for big entries (not in this place)
2. **It is cutting  the possibility of having the max. column value size**(max(longtext))  and leaving us only with the 767bytes as the maximum value of the column even though the column is a longtext. - Not acceptable => is here the extra query really neccessary? Or is there another way? (e.g.sql-side search and variable save => chosing action according the result)

Any help/tips on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance 3072 bytes are enough? You can use the [innodb_large_prefix](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) parameter in your mysql configuration in that case.

If 3072 bytes are not enough what I would do is adding a fixed lenght column (something like a varchar(256)) and use that one to create the index. When inserting/updating the record you can use [SUBSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to trim your long text to 256 char and populate the extra column with that value.

This of course works only if you care about smaller entries in meta_* like you said. Depending on the number of rows your disc usage will increase a little but this shouldn't be an issue in most cases.

Comment: Or is it better to split meta values to two tables?

Comment: This will add complexity to your select, and, if the result set is huge will slow down your query. Adding two varchar(256) is definitely faster than creating a new table with an 1:1 relation.

Comment: Give it a try, you shouldn't notice any performance difference.

Comment: Well I ment just spliting the table not creating a new table for each new entry :) you know, one would be `meta_id   |   user_id   |   meta_type   |   meta_value(varchar(255))` and the other one `meta_id   |   user_id   |   meta_type   |   meta_value(longtext)` both related to the user table, and new values would be inserted/updated for each table separatly - so what about now?

Comment: I don't see any way this could be better than simply adding one column. Also in this case how are you keeping the two table in sync? You can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only on one of them...but you want to insert in both.

Comment: There is no need of syncing I would use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only on the one with the smaller entries. It would be two completely separate tables each containing different types of values. From "meta_allsize" it would split to "meta_smalls" and "meta_biggs" is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. IMHO there's no need of the extra table, but hey, you can try and see what works better. I bet on the extra column :)